# Focus on next input field in react while using map to display a jsx field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I am trying to make a Wordle clone how do i focus on the next input field after onChange have fired (After user have entered a word)

```
import {useRef} from 'react';

const Mainarea = () => {
 // will use useState later in this    
const boxes = [{color: "white" , id:1 , userInput : ""} ,{color: "white" , id:2 , userInput : ""} ,{color: "white" , id:3 , userInput : ""} ,{color: "white" , id:4 , userInput : ""} ,{color: "white" , id:5 , userInput : ""}];

    var value = "" 
    const inputRef = useRef("");

    return (

        <div className="Mainarea">
            <div className="mainBoxArea">
            
            // This is the map function in question 
        {boxes.map(box => {
                value  = value + box.userInput;
            return(
            <div className="div" key = {box.id}>
                <input ref = {inputRef} className = "boxview" maxLength={1} type="text"/>
            
            </div>
        )})}
            </div>
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Mainarea;


----------
```

After user have added a word I want automatically focus on the next field as this map function will trigger 5 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have an array of `inputs` so you need an array of `refs`, and on the `handleChange` function you can go to the next `input` by incrementing the index by one and using the `focus` event on the target `input` on that index.

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const Mainarea = () => {
  // will use useState later in this
  const boxes = [
    { color: "white", id: 1, userInput: "" },
    { color: "white", id: 2, userInput: "" },
    { color: "white", id: 3, userInput: "" },
    { color: "white", id: 4, userInput: "" },
    { color: "white", id: 5, userInput: "" }
  ];

  var value = "";
  const inputRefs = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRefs.current = inputRefs.current.slice(0, boxes.length);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (i) => {
    if (i === boxes.length - 1) {
      return;
    }
    inputRefs.current[i + 1].focus();
  };



  return (
    <div className="Mainarea">
      <div className="mainBoxArea">
        {boxes.map((box, i) => {
          value = value + box.userInput;
          return (
            <div className="div" key={box.id}>
              <input
                ref={(el) => (inputRefs.current[i] = el)}
                className="boxview"
                maxLength={1}
                type="text"
                onChange={() => handleChange(i)}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mainarea;
```

[And this is working codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-cdn-cfe6m0?file=/src/inputs.js:0-1198)